# INSERT using a SELECT statement and also add a variable value to each row of the result at the same time in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `nameValue` that has 5 columns (Id,val,firstName,lastName,age). I use a select statement that gives firstName,lastName, age in multiple rows, lets say it returns 5 rows. Id is Auto-Increment. I want to add `val` to each of the 5 rows returned.

`$val=55; INSERT INTO nameValue (val,firstName,lastName,age) VALUES($val, SELECT fName,lName,age FROM nameAge WHERE age<25);` something like this where we are insert same variable $val to each of the 5 rows returned by the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the wrong way. Try this -

```
INSERT INTO nameValue (val,firstName,lastName,age)
SELECT $val, fName,lName,age FROM nameAge WHERE age < 25
```